# Is it possible to allow PHP not to show the server shared ip?

Tags: php, ip

I am using PHPproxy script loading it every time with a different IP

i.e

```
208.115.213.35/~acct/proxy

174.12.19.254/~acct/proxy

208.115.213.34/~acct/proxy

example.com/proxy
```

all links above show the same ip when I access this website  `http://www.whatsmyrealip.com/` using any of the links above instead of showing the ip used in each url, whatsmyrealip.com show my server shared ip server never mind which IP i use to access the website. Is it possible to be able to use a specific ip when I want to ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. Define "when I try", and "they" and "show" and "uses".

Comment: Edited the main post sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you are asking here, but the answer is probably no.

If my understanding of your problem is correct, you have a server that has multiple IP addresses, and you want to be able to control which IP address it uses to access the internet. In order to control this, you need to have control over the server's [routing table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table), which since you say this is a `shared box` is unlikely to be something you can control.

If my understanding your question is incorrect, or you would like more of an explanation, let me know.

Comment: you got it right, but no I own the server and I do have a root access it that helps ?

Comment: probably not to be honest, the owner of the server is unlikely to be happy if you start manipulating the routing table as it would affect other users of the server. Why does this particularly matter? What are your trying to do?

Comment: I have a client(s) who are game players, they want me to provide each one of them a separate proxy with separate IP so they can play online without getting caught from the same network (I guess they are not allowed to play from the same IP it counts as if one guys controls more than one account)


I thought its easy just install a php web proxy, but they told me then its a must that when using the php proxy and visiting the website (http://www.whatsmyrealip.com/), they need to see different IP for each which never happened !!!

ANY ONE KNOWS ?